# Z-Index not working within a Bootstrap Carousel

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, pug, z-index

I have a bootstrap carousel where one slide consists of 4 Css boxes (2 on top and 2 on the bottom). They have a shadow and the shadow of the top two boxes cover the one on the bottom.

[image]

I'm aware that elements have to be positioned so that the z-index applies, but setting the position (to `relativ)` and increasing the z-index on the lower elements doesn't work.

Is it due to the fact that one slide consists of two rows (upper and lower) and therefore the they have different parent (flex-)containers? I still don't understand why the Z-Index doesn't have a impact since `flex` should behave like `inline-block`.

Here is the code (in pug):

```
              .carousel-inner
                .carousel-item.active
                    .row.mt-lg-4.mt-2
                        .col-lg-6.col-12
                            .container-fluid.h-100
                                .carousel-card.d-flex.flex-nowrap.align-items-center
                                    .col-3.text-center
                                        img(src='img/examination-anxiety-icon.svg').img-fluid 
                                    .col-9
                                        h3 Header
                                        p.text-left "Text"
                        .col-lg-6.col-12
                            .container-fluid.h-100
                                .carousel-card.d-flex.flex-nowrap.align-items-center
                                    .col-3.text-center
                                        img(src='img/decision-difficulties-icon.svg').img-fluid  
                                    .col-9
                                        h3 Header
                                        p.text-left Text
                    .row
                        .col-lg-6.col-12
                           container-fluid.h-100
                                .carousel-card.d-flex.flex-nowrap.align-items-center
                                    .col-3.text-center
                                        img(src='img/mobbing-icon.svg').img-fluid  
                                    .col-9   
                                        h3 Header
                                        p.text-left Text
                        .col-lg-6.col-12
                            .container-fluid.h-100
                                .carousel-card.d-flex.flex-nowrap.align-items-center
                                    .col-3.text-center
                                        img(src='img/life-crisis-icon.svg').img-fluid  
                                    .col-9   
                                        h3 Header
                                        p.text-left Text
```

Comment: z-index is working with position fixed or absolute not with relative.

Comment: "Note: z-index only works on positioned elements (position: absolute, position: relative, position: fixed, or position: sticky)." https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Comment: @SandeepK.The `z-index` property also works with `position:relative`. The only value that will not work is **"static"**.

Answer (score 0):

you have to set additional css to the `.row` element.

```
... 
   .row.z-down
      ...
   .row.z-up
      ...
...
```

CSS:

```
.row { position: relative; }
.row.z-down { z-index: 0; }
.row.z-up { z-index: 1; }
```

Comment: That was my initial thought too, but it doesn't work. Neither setting the position and z-index of the row nor of the element has an impact. Is it maybe somehow related too Bootstrap?

Comment: Have you tried to force with `!important`?

Comment: Yes doesn't have an impact either..what is strange that the z-index works on the elements in relation to the rest of the page, e.g. the navbar, but somehow it does not effect the other elements in the carousel